# Trying to improve the runtime of macro

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a macro to import data in another workbook to my master log based on some criteria, but now that I'm running it on larger import files the runtime has slowed dramatically. My master log currently has over 900,000 rows of data and my current import has roughly 67,000 rows. Right now I would estimate it will take at least 12 hours to run for the current file being imported (the largest in my sequence), with smaller files to be imported after that.

The issue I have comes back to using Range.Find inside a For...To loop, I think. I'm guessing a method using variant arrays would improve my code dramatically, but I haven't used many arrays in the past and with the criteria I'm looking for I'm not entirely sure how to implement arrays this time.

```vb
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet 'master log
Dim uwb As Workbook, uws As Worksheet 'import file
Dim i, lrow, frow, urow As Long
Dim ftest As Range
Dim acct, oldstatus, newstatus As String

'(unnecessary code omitted)

urow = uws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To urow
    acct = uws.Cells(i, 1).Value
    newstatus = uws.Cells(i, 4).Value
    lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set ftest = ws.Range("A2:A" & lrow).Find(What:=acct, After:=ws.Range("A2"), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If ftest Is Nothing Then
        ws.Cells(lrow + 1, 1).Value = acct
        ws.Cells(lrow + 1, 2).Value = uws.Cells(i, 2).Value
        ws.Cells(lrow + 1, 4).Value = newstatus
    Else
        frow = ws.Range("A2:A" & lrow).Find(What:=acct, After:=ws.Range("A2"), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        oldstatus = ws.Cells(frow, 4).Value
        If newstatus <> oldstatus Then
            ws.Cells(frow, 3).Value = uws.Cells(i, 2).Value
            ws.Cells(lrow + 1, 1).Value = acct
            ws.Cells(lrow + 1, 2).Value = uws.Cells(i, 2).Value
            ws.Cells(lrow + 1, 4).Value = newstatus
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

My master log is formatted as

```
Account         Start_Date  End_Date    Status
1234567890      6/27/2012   9/24/2012   ABC
1234567890      9/24/2012   1/9/2013    DEF
1234567890      1/9/2013    1/15/2013   ABC
1234567890      1/15/2013   2/4/2013    GHI
1234567890      2/4/2013    2/16/2013   ABC
1234567890      2/16/2013   9/8/2014    GHI
1234567890      9/8/2014    9/24/2015   ABC
1234567890      9/24/2015   10/26/2015  JKL
1234567890      10/26/2015  11/16/2015  ABC
1234567890      11/16/2015              JKL
```

and the imported file is

```
Account         UPDATE_DATE Company_Status  Client_Status
1234567890      8/5/2019    PLW             GHI
```

Basically what my code is doing is looking through the log for the most recent status of each account in the import (master log always starts sorted by Account least to greatest and Start_Date oldest to newest, hence my use of xlPrevious), if the Status/Client_Status is different, then it will add the Update_Date as the End_Date in the found row of the log and start a new row at the bottom of the log with the new status information. If the import has an account not previously in the log, it will also add a new entry at the bottom of the log. If it is helpful, there will only be status update per account in the import file.

Thank you!

Comment: There are loads of examples on this website alone about improving code performance. The obvious things are `ScreenUpdating = False` and `CalculationMode = Manual`. However for such a big file you should really look into reading the data into an array first.

Comment: Looping through a variant array will definitely be **much faster** than `Range.Find`. But your log is approaching Excel limitations for worksheet rows, so perhaps you should consider a database program such as Access.

Comment: I'll have to do some more research into implementing arrays. The long term plan is to transfer the log into a SQL database and have a stored procedure that will update the data on a daily basis, but my SQL isn't quite up to par for writing that procedure and temporarily keeping it in Excel was my solution.